# Does an LNA with a dedicated Vbias pin affect impedance matching?

Tags: amplifier, voltage-regulator, impedance, impedance-matching, low-noise-amplifier

I am optimizing an impedance match for an LNA in my target frequency range using a Touchstone s2p that Qorvo provides for the [QPL9547 (datasheet)](https://www.qorvo.com/products/d/da007268).

The Vbias pin is separate from the RF-in pin.  I'm used to biasing a FET gate on the RF input pin (assuming this device is a FET) and the bias filter would typically affect the RF-in match (S11) on a FET.

The Vbias is broken out by itself and there isn't any information about how that Vbias pin is wired internally. If the Vbias pin isn't well isolated from the RF-in pin then the that internal bias-tee circuit in addition to any filtering I have for the low-noise voltage source feeding Vin might affect my S11 impedance match.

Can I just impedance-match RF-in (and RF-out) but ignore Vbias all together as part of the RF behavior, or should I consider Vbias's involvement in the match somehow?  Should I assume Vbias and RF-in are connected for matching purposes?

Here is their reference circuit.  (Pin1 is Vbias. Pin6 is a "shutdown" pin so ignore it for this question. R4 is a 3.32kOhm resistor)

[image: Qorvo QPL9547 Reference Circuit]

Comment: Best bet: ask a Qorvo apps engineer. Or get the demo board and do some measurements of your own. I think it's unlikely RF IN and VBIAS are directly connected. If they were, why not just connect R4 to the input trace, and avoid the stub produced by having the separate pin for "VBIAS"? But it's probably not wise to assume they're fully isolated, either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using an s2p file that the manufacturer supplied for you to design with the part, I think you should assume that the S-parameters were measured with the device operating, ie biassed, so already have any influence from the other pins of the package taken into account.

Note that the S-parameters have only been measured for the typical Idd of 65 mA, so could be different for other values of Idd, and so other values of R4.

Comment: Yep, the s2p is from Qorvo.  I have to change the "Vds" match so the influence included in their s2p will change.  I'm trying to understand if that change is negligible or something worth considering.

Comment: 'I have to change the Vds match' - you have to change the value of Vds from what was used to produce those S-parameters, or you won't be using the component values that they show on their example circuit? The s2p file is de-embedded to the device pins, so does not include the output biassing components. If the supply voltage is changed, then expect the S-parameters to change significantly.

Comment: The supply Vds will _not_ change, as you note the s2p is for a specific Idq and Vds. However, the matching circuit components for the supply bias (that I called the "Vds match") will change to fit the target frequency since S11 is only -5 in the 2m band.  The sample circuit is centered at 1.9GHz but we are shooting for 146MHz so a bit of Microwave Office optimization will tells us the component values we'll need to meet that. We can even use s2p's from cap and inductor vendors (eg muRata) to create .mdf's and optimize those to find the exact right parts.  At least, that is the plan anyway...